# How do I save the contents of a textview to a file, on Symbian?

Tags: java, java-me, symbian

How do I save the contents of a textview to a file, on Symbian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in [RMS](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/databaserms/), [here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=435) is example

Comment: but what if i restart the phone?? I think recordstore data gets lost after phone restarts.

Comment: @neha no RMS will stay persisted.