# Is RMS only temporary storage?

Tags: java, java-me, rms

Is the Record management System in J2ME a temporary storage system? Does it vanish after the application is closed?

Comment: isn't this already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013019/how-do-i-save-the-contents-of-a-textview-to-a-file-on-symbian/5013034#5013034) ??

Comment: @Jigar, you've been doing a great job finding duplicate posts.

Comment: @torrtruk This one was answered by me for the same OP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RMS](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/persist/) is only storage concept for using in j2me. Its not temporary storage. Its permanent storage while you deleting the application or RMS.

And some 3rd party databases also available for j2me. See this [list](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME).

Comment: "You can't access outside of midlet" -- not quite right, you can create a store which any other midlet can access using AUTHMODE_ANY.

Comment: but if i restart my phone,i think the recordstore will be deleted.is it?