# how to save persisting data in symbian using the phonegap?

Tags: cordova, symbian, web-storage

I am working on an application for different platforms: BB, iPhone, Android and symbian. This application has to store some data and I want this application to work offline so I am using the local storage of Phonegap, but unfortunately it doesn't support Symbian, and I searched for any workaround but got no result, also the web storage in HTML5 is only supported for Meego not symbian. So is there anyone faced this problem and solved it???

Comment: There's been a talk about this here but nobody could find a solution
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/57267b1b22675399 Also maybe it's not worth developing for Symbian anymore.

Comment: Thank you TDeBailleul, I saw this thread before and asked a question hoping anyone had found an answer, but apparently it has no solution

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, however this might help some one looking for answers

[How do I save the contents of a textview to a file, on Symbian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013019/how-do-i-save-the-contents-of-a-textview-to-a-file-on-symbian)